# Xamarin.android Microsoft.SQLite Always return no rows

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
  string path = Path.Combine(
         System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
          "Service.db3");

            SqliteConnection cn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + path + " ");

            List<String> entries = new List<string>();


            SqliteCommand sqCommand = (SqliteCommand)cn.CreateCommand();
            sqCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT ID FROM Members ";
            cn.Open();

  SqliteDataReader sqReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqReader.HasRows)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
```

that is my code I'm using but there is no row although I have 2 rows at the table
and if I used

> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
>   I got the table name that I created  I don't understand??

Comment: are you using the right nuget package?  The constructor for `SqlConnection` takes a path, not a connection string.  And how are you pre-populating your database?  This is a slightly non-trivial process, not something most people get right the first time.

Comment: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: I used sqlite-net-pcl this nuget package before but ummm I couldn't use it i was getting error no such table Members and it was created one

Comment: then you should solve those errors

Comment: I'm Trying I don't know where is the problem at my code or at my database

Comment: I suggest you make another post with the details of THAT problem

Comment: I figured the problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the answer now 
I have to make function create the db and table
I was creating the db with sqlite studio and save it

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Path.Combine(
     System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
      "Service.db3");

        SqliteConnection cn = new SqliteConnection("Filename=" + path);

        List<String> entries = new List<string>();


        SqliteCommand sqCommand = (SqliteCommand)cn.CreateCommand();
        sqCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Members ";
        cn.Open();

         SqliteDataReader sqReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (sqReader.HasRows)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
```

Try this